# A simple vote aggregation function

Tags: function, math, aggregation

I want to evaluate the acceptance rate of a proposal, where a proposal can receive two types of votes: namely positive and negative.

So the simplest function that comes to mind is  as follows:

```
p + n / p + n + \epsilon
```

However I would like to come up with a more sophisticated function which would satisfy the following two properties.

- The ratio of positive votes to the total amount of votes should always take precedence. So where `p1 = 5, n1 = 0, p2 = 99, n2 = 1` the function should calculate a higher acceptance rate for the first one.
- When the ratios are equal, the function should return a higher acceptance rate for the one with the higher number of total votes. So in the following case where `p1 = 1000, n1 = 0, p2 = 10, n2 = 0` again the first one should have a higher acceptance rate.

Another idea concerning the function could be the following:

```
w * [p / (p + n)] + (1 - w) * [(p + n) / maxV]
```

where maxV is the maximum number of votes that any proposal received and w is a real number in `[0..1]`.

This function satisfy the second condition whereas the guarantee does not extend to the first one. Finding a value for w to satisfy the system could be cumbersome thus I'm searching for a better solution.

Comment: There is no real-valued function that will satisfy both requirements. Would you like a proof, or a discussion of comparison functions and what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I would really appreciate the proof.

Comment: On reflection, I'm starting to suspect I was wrong. I am working on a function, and I'm prepared to eat my words if I find it...

Comment: Anxiously waiting for your response. Thanks so much for the interest.

Comment: @SinanEgilmez I think you mean `p1 = 1000, n1 = 1000, p2 = 10, n2 = 10`, and "when the ratios are equal *to 50%*"...